# Boot from USB with it's storage

Tags: partitioning, usb, live-usb, storage

I have a sandisk 128GB USB, I made a partition ex4 for the Ubunutu OS and the remaining for storage as fat32. I booted from my USB but in storage capacity it still shows memory as 4gb that was from my previous partition.I want to have all the 90gbs and as my storage and the remaining can be used as a place for OS.What should be my approach for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

### Bootable USB with storage

For comparison between Full install and Persistent install see: [How do I make my live ubuntu on a USB stick persistant?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1283839/how-do-i-make-my-live-ubuntu-on-a-usb-stick-persistant/1283905#1283905)

A standard Live install using Etcher, Startup Disk Creator, dd or Disks, uses the full disk for for the ISO9660 install. Starting with 19.10 a ghost persistent partition named "writable" was added. This partition can be converted to NTFS or FAT32 to make the unusable space on the disk usable for data: [Add NTFS Data Partition to Startup Disk Creator USB Install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198035/add-ntfs-data-partition-to-startup-disk-creator-usb-install)

A quick and simple way to create a Full install can be found here: [How should I make my partitions for a Full Install USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280737/how-should-i-make-my-partitions-for-a-full-install-usb/1280812#1280812). Note that space requirements for the OS are about 15GB, the remainder of the disk can be used for data.

Mkusb will make a bootable USB with adjustable Persistent and NTFS Data partitions, the data partition can be changed to FAT32 if the user likes: [Creating a bootable USB with saved configurations](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1260590/creating-a-bootable-usb-with-saved-configurations/1260780#1260780)

Comment: My laptop is fairly modern and so there are no screws to open it up and unmount the hard drive is there some way of doing it on the laptop itself. Also, what do you recommend is the best way to go forward Live or persistent. Thanks in advance

Comment: Unless you need to use the USB for installing Ubuntu I would recommend the Full install method shown on https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280737/how-should-i-make-my-partitions-for-a-full-install-usb/1280812#1280812. The flash process will destroy everything on the USB. Once the install is complete you will want to create a New User and password. Later you can delete the temporary user and set the Clock and Location. You can boot from another drive or toram to use GParted to expand the data partition and change it from NTFS to FAT32 if you wish. I think that sudodus is recommending the same.

Comment: If you need to be able to use the USB to install Ubuntu, you can either use mkusb to create a persistent USB as shown on https://askubuntu.com/questions/1260590/creating-a-bootable-usb-with-saved-configurations/1260780#1260780 or you can edit the Full install's bootloader to also boot ISO files.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main alternatives,

- [Persistent live system in USB drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181854/how-is-it-easier-to-make-a-persistent-live-drive-with-ubuntu-19-10)
- [*Installed* system in USB drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263746/ubuntu-doesnt-boot-from-usb-stick/1263749#1263749) - see details in the links from this link.

Ask for more details or other alternatives, if necessary.

Comment: My laptop is fairly modern and so there are no screws to open it up and unmount the hard drive is there some way of doing it on the laptop itself. Also, what do you recommend is the best way to go forward Live or persistent. Thanks in advance

Comment: If it is OK without encrypting the drive, I suggest that you try a compressed image of an installed system according to [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2447539&p=13974203#post13974203) and [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS). -- This way you need **not** unplug the internal drive.